# How get the array back out of a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the array back out of a function with console.log(mj[0]) it is returning undefined

```js
var ref = "somefile.json"
var mj = [];

async function ss() {
  await fetch(ref).then((respose) => {
    return respose.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    var a = Object.keys(data)
    mj.push(a)
  })
}
ss()

console.log(mj)
console.log(mj[0])
```

Comment: I made a stack snippet for you. Please add more details and description about what you intend to do and what is the actual problem here. Also, we will get an empty array here, because there is no file name as `somefile.json` around, so basically your request will fail and `then` statement on success will never run.

Comment: i have a file in my computer and it has an array. i just used "somefile.json" to ellaborate what i m trying to do.

Comment: We can't help you here with this information unless you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue. So you need to upload that file somewhere and refer this snippet to the live uploaded file.

Comment: FYI my Developer tool is giving the variale contaning an array with console.log(mj) but it failed to return me console.log(mj[0])

Comment: I can't tell what is your actual problem here. But this should work fine and the `mj[0]` should contain an array of object keys. Unless the promise does not fulfil the `console.log()` moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `console.log(mj[0])`, `mj` is still empty.
The reason is that your function `ss` is executed asynchronously.

You just have to await the method call:

```
var ref = "somefile.json"
var mj = [];

async function ss() {
  await fetch(ref).then((respose) => {
    return respose.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    var a = Object.keys(data)
    mj.push(a)
  })
}
// You also have to await here.
await ss()

console.log(mj)
console.log(mj[0])
```

This will work if you use promise chaining:

```
async function ss() {
  return fetch(ref).then((respose) => {
    return respose.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    var a = Object.keys(data)
    mj.push(a)
  })
}

ss().then(() => console.log(mj[0]));
```

Comment: thanks for your help, though I want to get the value of mj[0] out of this function.. is there any way I can store the array mj[0] in a global variable

Comment: If you want it to be global, you can still store it on the window: window.mj = []. However this is a different question as far as I see it. The issue in your code example is the asynchronicity.

Comment: I think I understand your comment now - if you want to keep using await, there is just one wait missing. See my edited answer. cheers.

Comment: It is throwing a silly error await is only allowed in async function

Comment: and if I try to put await ss() in a different async function mj[0] still giving undefined

Comment: i got my thing fixed with your help thank you very much.